# Key word transformation and blank filling

Tags: exam-questions

I'm having trouble trying to do these exercises of sentence transformation, where you have to fill in the blanks with 3-6 words, including the one in brackets, so that the new sentence has <strike>the same meaning as</strike> a *similar* meaning to the original one. This is the first.

> They left as soon as I entered the room. (had)
>   No _____________________ the room than they left.

Before knowing the answer, I thought it was something like *No [sth] I had entered the room than they left*, but I couldn't guess what *[sth]* could be and I didn't notice the inversion.
Here is the second.

> He told her because he believed it was true. (belief)
>   He told her ______________________ true.

I don't understand why they removed *because*, maybe I shouldn't write it... But they left *true*... And I think the solution doesn't contain the fragment *his belief was true*, since the thing that is true is the *it* of the first sentence. But I may be wrong...

**Edit.** This is not homework! Answering this question will mean neither relieving me of my duty nor making me able to do all the exercises of this kind. It'll just teach me two expressions that might come in handy one day (and maybe some useful tips too ;).

Comment: I'm pretty sure the first one is _No sooner had they entered the room..._ I'm at a loss for the second one, though; the best I can muster is _He told her his belief, that it was true,_ but I'm afraid that's rather clunky.

Comment: @J.R. Thank you! I think you meant *No sooner had I entered the room*...

Comment: Yes, correct. Nice catch.

Comment: He told her because of his belief that it was true. He told her since it was his belief that it was true. He told her since his belief was that it was true. He told her as his belief was that it was true. (These are in the order I wrote them as my ideas evolved. I think the last one, with the "as", is the best.)

Comment: @AdrianHHH, you cannot write more than 6 words...

Comment: "He told her **what he believed was** true", "He told her **since his belief was** true.

Comment: I can write as many words as I choose. You might desire that the answer should be 3-6 words, but that does not stop me from writing as many words as I like. I will leave condensing my suggested words to 6 or less to you. If I had seen a 6 word variation I would have written it as an answer.

Comment: @Peter your first option doesn't work - it has to have the word in parens if I understand the exercise correctly. Also in your second suggestion "his belief was true" changes the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: Human, we can tell you some answers, but that isn't going to help you answer similar questions in the future. Can you explain any more about why you're having trouble thinking of a solution? Maybe we can help you understand how to look at the first sentence to figure out your own answer.

Comment: @ColleenV, Maybe: "He told her **since he thought his belief was** true."

Comment: @Peter That makes more sense to me. Human thanks for adding more detail - I've voted to re-open.

Comment: He told her because *it was his belief* (= he believed) it was true.

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=it+is+my+belief%2Cit+is+our+belief&year_start=1675&year_end=2010&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20my%20belief%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cit%20is%20our%20belief%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Could you please separate this into two questions?  I'd like to be able to answer just the first question.

Comment: *He told her **in the belief that it was** true.* But this is just an Off-Topic guessing game - I don't endorse [this meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/).

Comment: Fumblefingers has nailed it. See OD: [She acted **in the belief that** she was doing good](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/belief)

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you! Was there any better place than this site for asking my question?

Comment: @Human: Other opinions may differ, but I don't think this kind of "please do my homework" question would be On Topic on any SE sites. But in any case, I don't think *either* of your two questions are well-posed. In any given real-world context most competent speakers would understand subtle nuances of difference between the "original" and "suggested alternative", so it's misleading to "teach" these examples to learners in a way that gives the impression the alternative phrasing is somehow precisely equivalent and thus transparently interchangeable with the original.

Comment: @FumbleFingers. This is not homework! (I should have added that...) Indeed, it's from a test I took some time ago. I spent enough time on those questions that I was able to remember and ask them here. As for the _precisely equivalent_ thing, I'd say that in all the languages I know, two factually different sentences hardly ever have _exactly_ the same meaning. I think these exercises are not really meant to test your competence in rephrasing sentences, but rather your knowledge of vocabulary, grammatical structures and idioms. The original phrasing is there just to give you the context.

Comment: When they write _He told her because he believed it was true. (belief) He told her _______ true_, they are probably asking "Do you know (and can you use) the expression _in the belief that_?". I think they are not asking for a precisely equivalent phrasing... I don't know whether this is true or not, but it seems plausible...

Comment: @Human: It's still *this kind of "please do my homework" question* regardless of whether it was set by your schoolteacher, an exam board, or some enterprising amateur on the Internet - though I'd suspect it's the latter (and a non-native speaker at that). You should note that [no sooner had I entered...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=no+sooner+had+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cno%20sooner%20had%20he%3B%2Cc0) is quaint/dated phrasing typical of a Victorian children's story, not something today's learners should want to use.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, at least you now know it isn't homework. :) And nope, it wasn't _set by some enterprising amateur on the Internet_ ahah. Anyway, thanks for the clarification, I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: @Human: Also note that for the second item, *in the belief that it was true* is equivalent to ***in good faith** [that it was true]*. Neither of which expressions carry any implication that the information was given ***because*** the speaker believed it to be true - simply that he ***did*** believe it, regardless of ***why*** he said it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first, as noted in the comments is:

- No **sooner had I entered** the room than they left.

Notice that we need to put the Subject after the auxiliary verb here. This is because there is a negative word in the Adjunct at the beginning of the sentence.

I think the second probably is:

- He told her **in the belief (that) it was** true.

This doesn't really say that he told her *because* he believed it was true. But these questions are often not very well designed.

Comment: Shouldn't _the second probably is_ be _the second is probably_? Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: @Human Thanks! They're both good, actually. My version is "marked" which means it is in an unusual position to give a specific effect. In this case it is meant to emphasise that I am not sure. The more usual position is indeed after the auxiliary verb (well spotted!).

Comment: Ok. Good to know :)

Comment: I've suggested an edit: _no sooner had they_ should be _no sooner had I_ ("as noted in the comments") and _he told her because it was true_ should be _he told her because he believed it was true_. But it has just been rejected. Could you please correct it yourself?

Comment: @Human Oops, good edit. Do it again while I waiting and I'll accept it.It will go through and you'll get the rep you deserve! Let me know when you've done it!

Comment: Nathan Tuggy didn't like my edit ahah

Comment: @Human Sorry! I went to grab a cup of tea. Hold on one sec! Stay there for a few minutes, I'll sort this out!

Comment: @Human Ok. Go for it. Do it again. It will go through this time!

Comment: @Human Hooray!!

Comment: @Human Please keep asking good questions!  :)

Comment: And I have also earned enough rep to upvote your answer :)

Comment: @Human Thank you! (in general, it's probably best to wait a day or two before accepting an answer. You might get better ones! Also people with other good ideas might not write you an answer if you've already accepted one ;) )